# Can my XBOX mimic these features from the PS4/5?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

With my PS4 and now the PS5 I noticed that when I do the following(described below), certain things happen, and I'm trying to figure out if the Xbox can do the same thing.

**I've noticed that with my PS4/5:**

1. When I have my TV(LG C1 and previously my Samsung QLED) off, and I
   power on the PS5 using the controller, the TV(both of them)
   automatically turns itself on and puts itself on the appropriate
   HDMI input.
2. When the TV is already powered on, but on another input that's not the PS input, and I hit the "home" button on the controller, it auto switches the HDMI input to that of the PS
3. Lastly, the PS4 and 5 can be controlled by the TV (both of them) remotes.

Not sure what this functionality is called otherwise I would have googled it but, I find these features to be pretty simple but cool and I'm wondering, is this something that I can do with my Xbox Series X? or Xbox in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called HDMI-CEC, although some vendors have rebranded it for their devices. LG calls it SIMPLINK, for instance.

The Xbox does support HDMI-CEC, but the behavior unfortunately is not too consistent depending on the setup. Here I have the Xbox connected to a receiver and then to a TV. The TV is always set to the same HDMI input port and the receiver does the selection of which device to output to the TV. I haven't tested this specific flow you mentioned, but I have issues with another device forcing the input to it multiple times when powered on.

Microsoft details the settings here: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/display-sound/hdmi-cec. As you can see, there is no mention of changing the input to it, but I'd expect that to be the case when turning it on.